# Getting text from the pointer till the end of the document in JS Word api

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

How can i get the text in range from the current location of the cursor till the end of the file? I use JavaScript Word api.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: As you can read in the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#getselection--), you have to get the Selection (the curser is an empty selection), and can then grab the text from the document retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
const doc = context.document;
const originalRange = doc.getSelection();
originalRange.load("text");
await context.sync();

var txt = originalRange.text;
```